# NSubstitute conditions for throwing exception other than parameters

Tags: unit-testing, exception, nsubstitute

I'm using NSubstitute to mock a class that my method under test uses.  This mocked class may throw a particular exception under certain conditions.

The method that I'm testing has some "retry" logic that it executes when it catches this exception.  I'm trying to test this retry logic.  So, I need a particular method of this mocked class to throw the exception sometimes, but not other times.  Unfortunately, the method that throws this exception has no parameters, so I can't base the throw logic on parameters.

How can I make the mocked object's method throw the exception either:

A) ...the first N times it's called
or
B) ...based on the parameters some other method that's called before it
or
C) ...under any other condition other than the parameters passed in

To give you a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do, my code is something like:

```cs
IDataSender myDataSender = GetDataSender();
int ID = GetNextAvailableID();
myDataSender.ClearData();
myDataSender.Add(ID,"DataToSend");
bool sendSuccess = false;
while (!sendSuccess)
{
   try
   {
      myDataSender.SendData();
      sendSuccess = true;
   }
   catch (IDCollisionException)
   {
      ID++;
      MyDataSender.ClearData();
      myDataSender.Add(ID,"DataToSend");
   }
}
```

So, I need to test my retry logic, and I need to simulate that IDCollisionException.  However, I can't have the SendData() throwing the exception every single time, or the retry loop will never succeed.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use [`When..Do`](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) and close over a local variable to get this behaviour.

```cs
const int throwUntil = 3;
var callsToSendData = 0;
var dataSender = Substitute.For<IDataSender>();

dataSender
    .When(x => x.SendData())
    .Do(x =>
    {
        callsToSendData++;
        if (callsToSendData < throwUntil)
        {
            throw new DbCollisionException();
        }
    });
```

Similarly, you can also use [callbacks](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) to locally capture parameters passed to other methods, and access them within the `Do` block (rather than just using a counter).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that the mock could reference local variables of the test method.